# Recueperar variables del metodo onConnected

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, google-api

Tengo un problema con unas variables que quiero recuperar de un metodo onConnected, estas variables contienen la latitud y la longitud actual de mi dispositivo y las quiero recuperar para almacenar en una variable global y poder usar esas variables globales en el metodo onMapReady().

**Este es mi metodo onConnected(), las dos variables que quiero convertir en globales son txtLatitud y txtLongitud, aqui en este metodo ya tienen un valor que se asigna recuperando mis coordenadas actuales;**

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        int leer = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (leer == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISOS, REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        ultimaPosicion = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (ultimaPosicion != null){
            latitudActual = String.valueOf(ultimaPosicion.getLatitude());
            longitudActual = String.valueOf(ultimaPosicion.getLongitude());

            txtLatitud.setText(latitudActual);
            txtLongitud.setText(longitudActual);

        }

    }
```

Y este es mi metodo onMapReady(), las variables que quiero recuperar como globales son para usarlas en esa linea de codigo:

> final LatLng ejemplo = new LatLng(19.4188761, -99.1552811)

el problema es que no puedo recuperarlas como globales, he intentado usar **this.prueba = txtLatidud**, pero el valor que me retorna es null

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        final LatLng ejemplo = new LatLng(19.4188761, -99.1552811);




        Toast.makeText(this,"Latitud: " + prueba, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(ejemplo)
                .title("Prueba")
                .snippet("Población: 2,965 millones")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
//                .alpha(.5f)
//                .flat(true)
                .draggable(true));

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ejemplo, 16));


    }
```

Codigo completo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String[] PERMISOS = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    };

    private static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Location ultimaUbicacion;
    Double latitudObtenida;
    Double longitudObtenida;
    private TextView txtLat;
    private TextView txtLon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         txtLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
         txtLon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLon);


        if (googleApiClient == null){
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        int leer = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (leer == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISOS, REQUEST_CODE);
        }


        final LatLng BUENOS_AIRES = new LatLng(-34.637936, -58.406372);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BUENOS_AIRES)
                .title("Prueba")
                .snippet("Población: 2,965 millones")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
//                .alpha(.5f)
//                .flat(true)
                .draggable(true));

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitudObtenida, longitudObtenida), 2.0f));

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        int leer = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (leer == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISOS, REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        ultimaUbicacion = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (ultimaUbicacion != null){
            latitudObtenida = ultimaUbicacion.getLatitude();
            longitudObtenida = ultimaUbicacion.getLongitude();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las variables `txtLatitud` y `txtLongitud` hacen referencia a `TextView`´s, no son los valores de latitud y longitud que necesitas, los valores que necesitas son :

`latitudActual` y `longitudActual`

estos tendrán valor cuando se llame el método `onConnected()` y son los que usarías aquí:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        final LatLng ejemplo = new LatLng(latitudActual, longitudActual);
    ...
    ...
```

---

Si el método `onConnected()` obtiene posteriormente al llamado de `onMapReady()` los datos de latitud y longitud entonces puedes llamar el método `moveCamera()` para que actualice la posición en el mapa.

Es importante conviertas los valores a `Double` mediante `Double.valueOf()`:

```
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitudActual), Double.valueOf(longitudActual)), 2.0f));
```

Comment: Si tienes razon en eso, latitudActual ylongitudActual son las variables que necesito usar, el problema es que se carga primero el onMapReady y luego el onConnected por eso mis variables llegan como null al metodo de onMapReady

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa  para eso se usa el método googleMap.moveCamera() 
 debes convertir los valores a Double mediante Double.valueOf() ya que los convertiste a String previamente, revisa la actualización.